# How to subscribe to global trackpad touch event in swift mac app?

Tags: swift, macos, gesture

How can I get a global touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded, touchesCancelled, mouseDown, and mouseUp? I know how to do it for my view, but how can I do it for a different application? I know it is possible because BetterTouchTool does it.

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Comment: I want to intercept trackpad gestures sent to another application similar to BTT. How can I do that? I have the gesture workin in an NSView that is mine.

Comment: Is [addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535472-addglobalmonitorforevents) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Willeke I think so. Thank you.

Comment: @Willeke Which mask do I use to receive touches (not clicks)?

Comment: I think I need to work at the CGEvent level

Comment: @michaelmesser, did you ever get this figured out? Searching for the answer myself. Thanks!

Comment: @ZackShapiro see https://github.com/asmagill/hs._asm.undocumented.touchdevice

Answer (score 0):

Use [CGEvent.tapCreate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1454426-tapcreate) to handle intercept GCEvents globally. CGEvents be turned into NSEvents.

Answer (score 0):

@2426021684 how where you able to use the NSEvent to get information about the gesture. I am looking to determine which direction a swipe is in. I can find out when it start/is in progress/ends but have not managed to figure out any way to determine in which direction the user is swiping.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://github.com/asmagill/hammerspoon_asm.undocumented/tree/master/touchdevice